# output wordpress list categories with count by name the parent category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I try to output wordpress categories with count at the end of each category's name by input the parent category in code somewhere.

The result of the code down below display categories with the count of posts at the end, but it display all categories.

Ex: I have a parent category name "alpha", and its child categories name are, Category A, Category B, Category C, Category D

I want the output display:

-Category A (5)

-Category B (2)

-Category C (6)

-Category D (7)

```
<?php
    $variable = wp_list_categories( array(
    'show_count' => true,
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'style'      => 'none'
    ) );
    echo $variable; 
?>
```

Comment: you mean to say display parent category with total  child category count in main parent category right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I just use the "child_of" in the array, and input the parent category ID in the value.

```
<?php
   $variable = wp_list_categories( array(
     'show_count'         => true,
     'orderby'             => 'name',
     'style'               => 'none',
     'hide_empty'         => 0,
     'child_of'            => 52
   ) );
   echo $variable; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Display current category wise child category with total post count

```
<?php
    $category_object           = get_queried_object();
    $current_category_taxonomy  = $category_object->taxonomy;
    $current_category_term_id  = $category_object->term_id;
     $current_category_name  = $category_object->name;

    $args = array(
        'child_of'            => $current_category_term_id,
        'current_category'    => $current_category_term_id,
        'depth'               => 0,
        'echo'                => 1,
        'exclude'             => '',
        'exclude_tree'        => '',
        'feed'                => '',
        'feed_image'          => '',
        'feed_type'           => '',
        'hide_empty'          => 0,
        'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'order'               => 'ASC',
        'orderby'             => 'name',
        'separator'           => '',
        'show_count'          => 1,
        'show_option_all'     => '',
        'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
        'style'               => 'list',
        'taxonomy'            => 'category',
        'title_li'            => __( $current_category_name ),
        'use_desc_for_title'  => 0,
    );
    wp_list_categories($args);
 ?>
```